Solve the equation $25\{x\}^2 −10x+ 1 = 0$
the problem
We denote the fractional part of the number x by $\{x\}$.  The sum of the solutions of the equation $25\{x\}^2
 −10x+ 1 = 0$ is...
my idea
I noted $x=a+b, a=\{x\}, b=[x] \implies 25a^2-10a+1-10b=  0 \implies (5a-1)^2=10b$ b must aleas be natural, and i think this might help...
i also thought of using the quadric formula but got to nothing useful.
hope one of you can help me!  thanks!

First of all, the definition of fractional part being given seems irrelevant for the rest of the problem statement you gave. Second, do you notice that it's $(5x-1)^2$ ?

When you say $25x^2-10x+1$, are there parts of that that's meant to be in curly braces?

@Arthur Nice creative question.  I also was wondering how to make sense of this posting.

I think you meant \{ but typed only { some times

Yes, I was also wondering how, in any way, the quadratic formula wouldn't work.

You could always calculate the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ to find how many values there are, in this case, it equals 0 so the only value for $x$ is $-b/(2a)$.

AH!!!!! NOW the question makes sense.  I'll post an answer.

Let's try to be understanding here. The OP forgot the backslashes before the curly braces, so the question came out looking trivial. I fixed that, so now we have a decent question.

Well, I admit that this problem is more interesting at 2nd glance, or rather that I was the one mistaken about it. I was going to write that "clearly" all roots are in $[0,1)$ where all $x$ satisfies $x={x}$. But I see I was missing something and this problem was trickier than I gave t credit for.

Following your approach, let $a=\{x\}$,
$$\begin{align*}
0\le a &< 1\\
-1\le5a-1&<4\\
0\le(5a-1)^2&<16\\
0\le b &<1.6
\end{align*}$$
For each possible $b = \lfloor x\rfloor$, solve for $a$ and verify its value:
$$\begin{align*}
b&=0: & (5a-1)^2 &= 0\\
&& a &= \frac15\\
&& x &= \frac15 + 0\\
b&=1: & (5a-1)^2 &= 10\\
&& 5a-1 &= \pm \sqrt{10}\\
&& 5a &= 1+\sqrt{10} \quad\text{(negative case rejected)}\\
&& x &= \frac{1+\sqrt{10}}{5}+1 = \frac{6+\sqrt{10}}{5}
\end{align*}$$
So the sum of the solutions is $\dfrac{7+\sqrt{10}}{5}$.

Hints:
Prove

For $x\le 0$ we have $25\{x\}^2 −10x+ 1 \ge 1$
For $x\ge 3$ we have $25\{x\}^2 −10x+ 1 < -4$
For $x\in [0,1)$ we have $\{x\} = x$. Solve the equation.
For $x\in [1,2)$ we have $\{x\} = x-1$. Solve the equation.
For $x\in [2,3)$ we have $\{x\} = x-2$. Solve the equation.

You should get exactly two solutions.

Okay so let $\{x\} = a$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=b$.
Then $25\{x\}^2 -10x + 1 =25a^2 -10a -10b + 1=0$.  Let's treat $-10b+1$ as thought it were a constant and solve for $a$.
By quadratic formula $a = \frac {10\pm \sqrt{10^2- 4\cdot 25\cdot (-10b+1)}}{2\cdot 25}$
Now $10^2 - 4\cdot 25(-10b+1)= 1000b$ and $\sqrt{10^2 - 4\cdot 25(-10b+1)}= \sqrt{1000b}=10\sqrt{10b}$.  So we
So $a = \frac {10 \pm 10\sqrt {10b}}{50}=\frac 15\pm \frac 15\sqrt{10b}$.
But $0 \le a < 1$ so we must have $a = \frac 15(\sqrt{10b} + 1)$
And we must have $0 \le \frac 15(\sqrt{10b} + 1) < 1$.
Can you take it from there?

$0 \le \sqrt{10b} + 1 < 5$ so


$-1 \le \sqrt{10b} < 4$ but $\sqrt{10b}\ge 0$ so


$0 \le \sqrt{10b} < 4$ so


So $0 \le 10b < 4^2=16$.  But $b\in \mathbb Z$ so $b = 0$ or $1$.


 If $b=0$ we have $a=\frac 15$ and $x=\frac 15$ and $25(\frac 15)^2 -10(\frac 15)+1=0$.  And if $b=1$ we have $a =\frac 15 +\frac 15\sqrt{10}\approx 0.83$.  And $x = a +b= \frac 65 +\frac 15\sqrt{10}$.  If we test $25\{x\}^2-10x + 1= 25(\frac 1{25} +\frac 2{25}\sqrt{10} + \frac 1{25}\cdot 10) - \frac {60}5-\frac {10}5\sqrt{10} + 1=(1+2\sqrt{10}+10)-12-2\sqrt{10} + 1 = 0$.


Plug in $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$ and set up the quadratic equation as $a\{x\}^2+b\{x\}+c=0$ with coefficoents dependong on $\lfloor x \rfloor$. Then find integer values of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ that meet the requirement $0\le\{x\}<1$.
Here, this procedure gives
$25\{x\}^2-10\{x\}+(1-10\lfloor x\rfloor)=0$
and from the quadratic formula:
$\{x\}=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{10\lfloor x\rfloor}}{5}$
This must be real (so $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is nonnegative) and lie between $0$ and $1$ possibly including $0$. If we choose the $\pm$ sign as positive, we must then have
$1+\sqrt{10\lfloor x\rfloor}<5\implies 0\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le1$
Choosing the $\pm$ sign as negative yields
$1-\sqrt{10\lfloor x\rfloor}\ge0\implies\lfloor x\rfloor=0$
The roots are then constructed accordingly.

Thus in addition to the double root at $1/5$ we would have without the fractional part sign there is one more nondegenerate root $(6+\sqrt{10})/5$ between $1$ and $2$.

